# How to hide particular cell of Collection View in such way that there would be no empty space?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

When the collectionView gets loaded, is there any way to hide a particular cell? For example, The list has a total of 10 items. I want the collectionView to show 9 items, the second item will be ignored. Currently, I am having

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
             if indexPath.item == 1 {
                let item = list[indexPath.item] as? ChatEntity else {
                let dummyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DummyCell", for: indexPath) as! DummyCell
                dummyCell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                dummyCell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
                return dummyCell
            }
        let cell = ....
        ...............
        return cell
    }
```

But it show empty blank space in the place of that 2nd item. Is there any way to view the list without that empty space?

Comment: Surely it shows your `DummyCell` instead of "empty blank space"? Do you want it to show `DummyCell`? If not, how about returning one item fewer in your `numberOfItems` method?

Comment: @Sweeper. Dummy cell is of height 0. so it should not show anything but in my case, it is showing blank space. `numberOfItems` varies in runtime due to batch updates and thats why I was trying to handle the out-of-bound error from collectionView(cellForItemAt:_) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer would be, you can simply set the height of the particular cell as 0.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    if indexPath.item == 2 {
        return CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: check code again i made changes to previous answer